# Tikz-pictures in prooftrees

Tags: tikz-pgf, bussproofs

I have a problem with the `bussproofs` package regarding the use of `tikz` pictures in it. All that I can find on the web seems to assume that one only wants to put simple formulas in the prooftree. But for my application, short graphs are the elements of the prooftree.

This is what I got so far, with the graph abstracted for simplification:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\newcommand{\tikzdefault}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=15mm and 12mm, semithick, every text node part/.style={align=center}] #1 \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{node} = [circle, draw, fill=white, text=black, minimum size = 5mm]
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{}
  \UnaryInfC{\begin{figure}[h]
             \scalebox{0.8}{
             \tikzdefault{
               \begin{scope}
                 \node[node] (v1) [] {$v$};
               \end{scope}
             }
             }
             \end{figure}
  }
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

I do not have too much experience with LaTeX at all, but I hope someone here has a solution.

Comment: I just edited my post sucht that it provides a MWE. Well, not completely, because it is not working due to the problem I have.

Comment: You are right, I fixed those two point. But it still does not work the way I want it to, I am afraid.

Comment: Actually, without the figure environment and the centering it works out well. Many thanks! Sometimes I just need a second pair of eyes.

Comment: @campa Do you want to answer? The existing answer is mistaken, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @campa why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I didn't even remember writing it... But I think it was because I wasn't satisfied with it and the community feedback wasn't overwhelmingly positive `:-)`

Comment: @campa It was some time ago, indeed... should we close the question as solved in comment?